# Delphi Rio 10.3.3 Call Showmessage on form create caused non styled message box

Tags: android, delphi, native, firemonkey, messagebox

I develop an application for android that has style. but when call showmessage in onformcreate of main form, the messagebox has android native style and my style didn't applied to it.

i try to apply style before Application.Initialization but nothing happend.

please help me.

Thanks

Comment: If you call showmessage in the other, common event, for example button's onclick, does the dialog look right?

Comment: yes, after form creation everything is ok and i have styled showmessage

Comment: OK, than place TTimer on the form and set Interval to some short value, for example 500(ms). Place your showmessage in the ontimer event for that timer (Do not forget to disable timer in that event handler, to make it trigger only once!) Of course if you are checking some condition for showmessage, do it simply in the ontimer event.

Comment: very good, perhaps your method works, but i want to know what causes this behavior of showmessage, i think there must be a place to apply styles to overcome nonstyled showmessages